# I want to echo all classNames that have the same userid in php

Tags: php, sql, echo

code here :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$userId1 = $_SESSION['user']['userId'];
$searchQuery = "SELECT ClassName FROM classrooms WHERE userid = '{$userId1}'";
echo "abc";
if ($mysqli->query($searchQuery) === TRUE) {
    echo "epic";
    while($row = $searchQuery->fetch_object()) {
        echo $row['ClassName'];
    }
}
```

I am trying to echo all instances where the userId in the classrooms table is equal to the session userId.  HELP.

this is the table that we are using to track the users classrooms I'm using mysqli.

```
ClassName  userid
yoink      25
lol        25
haha       6
yoinks     25
yeet       25
yeet1      25
```

Turns out, my post is mostly code. So let me give some background details. I'm trying to make a table that will disply the classroom name depending on the userID. So user 25 will have classrooms yoink,lol,yoinks,yeet, and yeet1. But  the if statement (our query) doesn't actually do anything.

Many thanks

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should resolve imminently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$searchQuery` is a string!!! And not a result handle which would have been returned from `$mysqli->query()` but you did not capture it.

So change the code to

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$userId1 = $_SESSION['user']['userId'];
$searchQuery = "SELECT ClassName FROM classrooms WHERE userid = '$userId1'";
echo "abc";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($searchQuery) === TRUE) {
    echo "epic";
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        //echo $row['ClassName'];
        // you fetch an OBJECT so address it as an object
        echo $row->ClassName;
    }
}
```

#### However - Big Warning

> Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$userId1 = $_SESSION['user']['userId'];

$sql = "SELECT ClassName FROM classrooms WHERE userid = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userId1);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    echo $row->ClassName;
}
```